# How to find very old history of commands in Linux CentOS?

Tags: centos

One of my questions on here has a lot of views and I have yet to select the best answer. Unfortunately, I cannot remember how I solved my problem.

The problem involved installing some stuff from `yum`. So I did:

history | grep yum

But I got no results, probably because I ran those commands many months ago, some time around January I think...

Is there any way to dig up that old history?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also view the Yum transaction log in `/var/log/yum.log` to see which packages were installed/updated/removed over time.

Comment: This is really useful. I think this will allow me to reconstruct what I did.

Answer (score 3):

Try with "yum history list all". Follwoing is a link to yum history details.

http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/16/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-Yum-Transaction_History.html

Comment: That command doesn't work at all on my CentOS machine.